# Fetching documents from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

My data structure is like this.

```
{
"Item" : {
    "CreateTimestamp" : {
        "@value" : "2012-12-31 01:48:24"
    },
    "EventList" : {
        "Event" : [ {
            "@eventId" : "5",
            "@eventName" : "Bullets"
        }, {
            "@eventId" : "33",
            "@eventName" : "ItemMaster"
        }]
    },
    "DirNumber" : {
        "@value" : "10713024"
    },
    "MNumber" : {
        "@value" : "10713024"
    }
}}}
```

I want to fetch the data using 'DirNumber' only. I want the query in java?Please help

Comment: are you using spring with java?

Answer (score 1):

On the MongoDB shell you can easily do:

```
db.collection.find( { 'Item.DirNumber.@value' : "10713024" } );
```

But I would advice you to **not** use `@` as part of a field name.

Writing the same query in Java should be easy if you'd read the documentation at http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-java-driver/#getting-a-set-of-documents-with-a-query

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ItemDO is your POJO,

```
public interface ItemRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<ItemDO, Serializable> {
  @Query("{DirNumber.@value:?0}")
  List<ItemDO> findByDirNumber(String value);
}
```

I don't see _id field in your json. This method will not work if your data is not in correct format.